# Firebase Analytics Event Unable to see in Firebase Dashboard

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I Create a Demo Project for Firebase Analytics I can see my event title and Parameters value in Realtime but after 24 hour I can't see my all event in Firebase Dashboard I Can only see the Event title name I can't able to see the parameters name, Does anyone know how can i resolve this issue.